# How do I check if a combination of multiple data exists

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

This is how I have my database structured:

[image]

The following checks if flight MK2345 exists

```
fbSearch: function(){
                var key;
                var childData;              
                firebase.database().ref('/flights/').orderByChild("flight").equalTo('MK2345').on('value', function (snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                            key = childSnapshot.key;
                            childData = childSnapshot.val();
                            console.log(childSnapshot.key)
                        });
                    }else{
                        console.log('not existing')
                    }
                })              
            }
```

but I want it to check if the combination flight date and origin exists.
As example:
I'd like to check if the following combination exists:
Date: 2019/07/23
Flight: MK1234
origin: AMS

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. So in your case something like `"origin_date": "AMS_2019/07/24"` (my favorite airport btw ). For a longer example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Thanks Frank, that was the information I was looking for!